# UIScrollView setContentOffset:(0,0) changes view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uikeyboard

I am trying to move my UIScrollView to make way for the keyboard when the keyboard is shown.

What's weird is the scrollview is moving *too much*.  I noticed that if I even just set the content offset of the scrollview to (0,0) it still moves the view down.  What's bizarre, is the contentOffset of the scrollview is 0,0 before I set it!  Whattt!

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"%f %f", scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) animated:YES];
}
```

This prints (0,0) but if I comment the second line, the view doesn't move.  Does setContentOffset have weird secondary consequences?

Comment: It calls scrollViewDidScroll, so maybe you are doing something there.

Comment: @Odrakir nope didn't implement any other methods

Comment: Then post the code where you create the scrollView and set its content. Because that line by itself works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)notification {
CGFloat ay = 150;
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, textField.frame.origin.y-ay) animated:YES];
}
```

Here change the value of ay as per your requirement. Depends on how much you want the scrollview to move.

Comment: You really aren't answering my question, of course if I set ay correctly it'll offset the move.